# Fetch the battery status of my MacBook with Swift

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, battery, batterylevel

I want to setup a Playground to fetch the battery status of my macbook.

I have already tried the following:

```
import Cocoa
import IOKit
import Foundation

var blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()
```

I am currently receiving an error as below

> Use of unresolved identifier 'IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It doesn't work in a Playground, but it works in a real app.

I couldn't access the `IOPowerSources.h` header file with Swift and `import IOKit` only, though: I had to make a bridge to Objective-C.

**Here's my solution:**

1. Add `IOKit.framework` to your project (click `+` in `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`)
2. Create a new empty `.m` file, whatever its name. Xcode will then ask if it should make a "bridging header". Say YES.
3. Ignore the `.m` file. In the new `YOURAPPNAME-Bridging-Header.h` file that Xcode just created, add the line `#import <IOKit/ps/IOPowerSources.h>` *(and don't add `import IOKit` in your Swift file)*
4. You can now access most of the `IOPowerSources` functions.

**Example:**

```
func getBatteryStatus() -> String {
    let timeRemaining: CFTimeInterval = IOPSGetTimeRemainingEstimate()
    if timeRemaining == kIOPSTimeRemainingUnlimited {
        return "Plugged"
    } else if timeRemaining == kIOPSTimeRemainingUnknown {
        return "Recently unplugged"
    } else {
        let minutes = timeRemaining / 60
        return "Time remaining: \(minutes) minutes"
    }
}

let batteryStatus = getBatteryStatus()
print(batteryStatus)
```

**Another example**, with `IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo`:

```
let blob = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesInfo()
let list = IOPSCopyPowerSourcesList(blob.takeRetainedValue())
print(list.takeRetainedValue())
```

Think to release all retained CFValues (here: blob & list) at the function end with:
CFRelease(value) >> here: CFRelease(blob) & CFRelease(list)

Result:

> (
> {
> "Battery Provides Time Remaining" = 1;
> BatteryHealth = Good;
> Current = 0;
> "Current Capacity" = 98;
> DesignCycleCount = 1000;
> "Hardware Serial Number" = 1X234567XX8XX;
> "Is Charged" = 1;
> "Is Charging" = 0;
> "Is Present" = 1;
> "Max Capacity" = 100;
> Name = "InternalBattery-0";
> "Power Source State" = "AC Power";
> "Time to Empty" = 0;
> "Time to Full Charge" = 0;
> "Transport Type" = Internal;
> Type = InternalBattery;
> }
> )