# Getting CPU,RAM info using IOKit in swift

Tags: swift, macos

I need to get information about CPU, RAM, Battery usage in mac application.

I can get all those information by using `vm_stat`,`top`,`system_profiler` using `NSTask`.

But I can't use those if I enable sandbox.

I can't find anything because the documentation for that is very poor(or I didn't find anything I guess).

So, what are the functions I can use to get the info about the system? Like using [`IOPowerSources.h`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IOKit/Reference/IOPowerSources_header_reference/) I can get information about the Battery.

Can anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: Answer for the battery status: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31659561/2227743. // For easy CPU status and many more, there's always SystemKit: https://github.com/beltex/SystemKit

Comment: @EricD It's embarrassing to say but I've already checked `SystemKit` and I can't understand because I come from Java background where most of the classes and methods are self explanatory by their names and they also maintain good documentation(same goes to swift). And also I tried to use `SystemKit` but there is an error stated there are no shared framework schemes